# Shimming dependencies in requireJS: shorthand vs longhand notation

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I've got the following shim configuration being used by RequireJS:

```
shim: {
    'thirdParty/jquery.jqGrid': ['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'thirdParty/grid.locale-en']
}
```

I am wondering if this is **exactly the same** as this notation:

```
shim: {
    'thirdParty/jquery.jqGrid': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'thirdParty/grid.locale-en']
    }
}
```

To the best of my understanding they are equivalent, but I'm experiencing different outputs when generating a file through r.js.

I am using RequireJS v2.1.9

Comment: I see no difference in meaning between the two. How does the output of `r.js` differ? Also v2.1.9 is old and may have bugs that have been fixed in later versions. Current is 2.1.22.

Comment: Yeah. Just saw that 2.1.22 is current. Going to take a stab at updating. The output is different in that all the shimmed dependencies are missing. The longhand notation includes them all, but the shorthand does not.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to update RequireJS and R.js resolves the issue. There was a bug in an older version which caused dependencies to not be detected.